# annotation disclosure button segue to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, uitableview, segue

i got a map with 3 annotation pins with disclosure buttons on it, i want to set a segue on the disclosure button such that when i click the button, it brings me to my `UITableViewController` called "`TableViewController`"

here are the codes: mapview.m

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pinView"];
    if (!pinView) {
        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinView"];
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;





        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    } else {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control

{

 // what do i write here?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect your MapController with the TableViewController with a segue named with an identifier (e.g. ABC) , then call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ABC" sender:self];
```

in your calloutAccessoryControlTapped method

Comment: sorry im new to objective c, 1)how do i connect my map controller to tableviewcontroller? 2)how d i create a segue with an identifier? @user1256663

Comment: did you set up your controllers in storyboard?

Comment: yes i did, i have a mapcontroller, tableview and webview controller

Comment: You CTRL+Dray from one Controller to another to create segue in Storyboard, and click on the segue to name it with an identifier. See if this tutorial will be helpful: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/06/21/storyboard-segues.html   Good Luck